# Add hyperlink to node text on a collapsible tree

Tags: d3.js

I would like to add hyperlink on the node text in the [collapsible tree example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).

How can I do this?

Comment: There is already a click handler function for each node, why don't you just use it to perform whatever action you'd like to perform with a hyperlink?

Comment: Well, the click handler is attached to the circle in the example and there is (afaik) no way to add a click handler to a text element, so this is really valid question. In fact, I can't figure out how to do this either. Right now, I draw a second element with an `click` handler that redirects

Comment: And the click handler on the circle is attached to expand/collapse and we don't want to break that.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a Javascript/svg/d3js noob, but I "solved" this by placing a hyperlinked transparent rectangle over the text, this workaround is available as a [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/serra/5012770).:

```
nodeEnter
  .append("a")
     .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "http://www.example.com/flare/" + d.id; })
  .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "clickable")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -60 : 10; })
      .attr("width", 50) //2*4.5)
      .attr("height", 12)
      .style("fill", "lightsteelblue")
      .style("fill-opacity", .3)        // set to 1e-6 to make transparent          
      ;
```

I added an additional [`clickable` style](https://gist.github.com/serra/5012770#file-index-html-L5) and [add `.on("click", click)` to the circle](https://gist.github.com/serra/5012770#file-index-html-L91) instead of the group (`g`) element.

This works, but has the drawback that the size of the clickable rect does not size with the text of the label.

I'm really looking forward to a better solution, so +1 for your question!

Answer (score 5):

If you remove the click handler on the global node and attach 2 different click handlers:

- One for the circle
- One for the text

You can have a different behaviour when clicking the text. If you style that element a bit it can look exactly as a hyperlink.

Check out my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/empie/EX83X/

Click Handlers

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; });

      nodeEnter.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; }).on("click", click);;

      nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .attr("class", "hyper").on("click", clack);

    function clack(d) {
        alert(d.name);
    }
```

And CSS:

```
.hyper {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.hyper:hover {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added another line of text to the node with some info about the link, like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.path; })
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "clickable")
    .attr("y", 16)
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.label; })
```

where path and label have the data you want for each node.